# Time difference check

Tags: r

I have a `DF_1` that shows the hospital admission date (date and time), the hospital discharge date (date and time) and whether the patient is a hospital readmission less than 30 days. Look:

```
ID <- c(111,222,222,333,444,444,555,666,1010,1010,1010)
PATIENT_ADMISSION <- c('18/03/2022 15:30','24/03/2022 12:28','27/03/2022 01:38','31/03/2022 08:53','16/04/2022 22:45','22/04/2022 13:15','05/04/2022 05:44','30/03/2022 06:16','10/01/2022 17:30','16/03/2022 22:00','08/04/2022 14:49')
PATIENT_DISCHARGE <- c('01/04/2022 11:20','26/03/2022 12:56','27/03/2022 17:52','01/04/2022 16:15','17/04/2022 12:26','25/04/2022 14:54','05/04/2022 11:44','07/04/2022 05:23','12/01/2022 06:35','06/04/2022 11:35','12/04/2022 12:36')
PATIENT_READMISSION_30D <- c('N','N','Y','N','N','Y','N','N','N','N','Y')
DF_1 <- data.frame(ID,PATIENT_ADMISSION,PATIENT_DISCHARGE,PATIENT_READMISSION_30D)
```

I want to include one more information in `DF_1`: I want to know if this readmission (PATIENT_READMISSION_30D = Y) happened within 72 hours. Thus, my `DF_1` would have one more variable and would be presented as follows:

```
ID <- c(111,222,222,333,444,444,555,666,1010,1010,1010)
PATIENT_ADMISSION <- c('18/03/2022 15:30','24/03/2022 12:28','27/03/2022 01:38','31/03/2022 08:53','16/04/2022 22:45','22/04/2022 13:15','05/04/2022 05:44','30/03/2022 06:16','10/01/2022 17:30','16/03/2022 22:00','08/04/2022 14:49')
PATIENT_DISCHARGE <- c('01/04/2022 11:20','26/03/2022 12:56','27/03/2022 17:52','01/04/2022 16:15','17/04/2022 12:26','25/04/2022 14:54','05/04/2022 11:44','07/04/2022 05:23','12/01/2022 06:35','06/04/2022 11:35','12/04/2022 12:36')
PATIENT_READMISSION_30D <- c('N','N','Y','N','N','Y','N','N','N','N','Y')
PATIENT_READMISSION_72H <- c('','','Y','','','N','','','','','Y')
DF_1 <- data.frame(ID,PATIENT_ADMISSION,PATIENT_DISCHARGE,PATIENT_READMISSION_30D,PATIENT_READMISSION_72H)
```

Therefore, I would like to know how it is possible to check and include this new variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on readmission since the last discharge:

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(lubridate))

ID <- c(111,222,222,333,444,444,555,666,1010,1010,1010)
PATIENT_ADMISSION <- c('18/03/2022 15:30','24/03/2022 12:28','27/03/2022 01:38','31/03/2022 08:53','16/04/2022 22:45','22/04/2022 13:15','05/04/2022 05:44','30/03/2022 06:16','10/01/2022 17:30','16/03/2022 22:00','08/04/2022 14:49')
PATIENT_DISCHARGE <- c('01/04/2022 11:20','26/03/2022 12:56','27/03/2022 17:52','01/04/2022 16:15','17/04/2022 12:26','25/04/2022 14:54','05/04/2022 11:44','07/04/2022 05:23','12/01/2022 06:35','06/04/2022 11:35','12/04/2022 12:36')
PATIENT_READMISSION_30D <- c('N','N','Y','N','N','Y','N','N','N','N','Y')
DF_1 <- tibble(ID,PATIENT_ADMISSION,PATIENT_DISCHARGE,PATIENT_READMISSION_30D)

DF_1 |>
  rename_with(~ str_remove_all(., "PATIENT_")) |> # Just to reduce the text
  group_by(ID) |>
  mutate(across(c(ADMISSION, DISCHARGE), dmy_hm),
    READMISSION_72H = case_when(
      READMISSION_30D == "Y" &
      difftime(ADMISSION, lag(DISCHARGE), units = "hours") <= 72 ~ "Y",
      READMISSION_30D == "Y" &
        difftime(ADMISSION, lag(DISCHARGE), units = "hours") > 72 ~ "N",
      TRUE ~ NA_character_
      )
  )
#> # A tibble: 11 × 5
#> # Groups:   ID [7]
#>       ID ADMISSION           DISCHARGE           READMISSION_30D READMISSION_72H
#>    <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>           <chr>          
#>  1   111 2022-03-18 15:30:00 2022-04-01 11:20:00 N               <NA>           
#>  2   222 2022-03-24 12:28:00 2022-03-26 12:56:00 N               <NA>           
#>  3   222 2022-03-27 01:38:00 2022-03-27 17:52:00 Y               Y              
#>  4   333 2022-03-31 08:53:00 2022-04-01 16:15:00 N               <NA>           
#>  5   444 2022-04-16 22:45:00 2022-04-17 12:26:00 N               <NA>           
#>  6   444 2022-04-22 13:15:00 2022-04-25 14:54:00 Y               N              
#>  7   555 2022-04-05 05:44:00 2022-04-05 11:44:00 N               <NA>           
#>  8   666 2022-03-30 06:16:00 2022-04-07 05:23:00 N               <NA>           
#>  9  1010 2022-01-10 17:30:00 2022-01-12 06:35:00 N               <NA>           
#> 10  1010 2022-03-16 22:00:00 2022-04-06 11:35:00 N               <NA>           
#> 11  1010 2022-04-08 14:49:00 2022-04-12 12:36:00 Y               Y
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Update to use `between` to handle possible negative hours per the below comment:

```r
library(tidyverse)
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(lubridate))

ID <- c(111,222,222,333,444,444,555,666,1010,1010,1010)
PATIENT_ADMISSION <- c('18/03/2022 15:30','24/03/2022 12:28','27/03/2022 01:38','31/03/2022 08:53','16/04/2022 22:45','22/04/2022 13:15','05/04/2022 05:44','30/03/2022 06:16','10/01/2022 17:30','16/03/2022 22:00','08/04/2022 14:49')
PATIENT_DISCHARGE <- c('01/04/2022 11:20','26/03/2022 12:56','27/03/2022 17:52','01/04/2022 16:15','17/04/2022 12:26','25/04/2022 14:54','05/04/2022 11:44','07/04/2022 05:23','12/01/2022 06:35','06/04/2022 11:35','12/04/2022 12:36')
PATIENT_READMISSION_30D <- c('N','N','Y','N','N','Y','N','N','N','N','Y')
DF_1 <- tibble(ID,PATIENT_ADMISSION,PATIENT_DISCHARGE,PATIENT_READMISSION_30D)

DF_1 |>
  rename_with(~ str_remove_all(., "PATIENT_")) |> # Just to reduce the text
  group_by(ID) |>
  mutate(across(c(ADMISSION, DISCHARGE), dmy_hm),
         READMISSION_72H = case_when(
           READMISSION_30D == "N" ~ NA_character_,
           READMISSION_30D == "Y" &
             between(difftime(ADMISSION, lag(DISCHARGE), units = "hours") |> 
                       as.integer(), 0, 72) ~ "Y",
           TRUE ~ "N"
         )
  )
#> # A tibble: 11 × 5
#> # Groups:   ID [7]
#>       ID ADMISSION           DISCHARGE           READMISSION_30D READMISSION_72H
#>    <dbl> <dttm>              <dttm>              <chr>           <chr>          
#>  1   111 2022-03-18 15:30:00 2022-04-01 11:20:00 N               <NA>           
#>  2   222 2022-03-24 12:28:00 2022-03-26 12:56:00 N               <NA>           
#>  3   222 2022-03-27 01:38:00 2022-03-27 17:52:00 Y               Y              
#>  4   333 2022-03-31 08:53:00 2022-04-01 16:15:00 N               <NA>           
#>  5   444 2022-04-16 22:45:00 2022-04-17 12:26:00 N               <NA>           
#>  6   444 2022-04-22 13:15:00 2022-04-25 14:54:00 Y               N              
#>  7   555 2022-04-05 05:44:00 2022-04-05 11:44:00 N               <NA>           
#>  8   666 2022-03-30 06:16:00 2022-04-07 05:23:00 N               <NA>           
#>  9  1010 2022-01-10 17:30:00 2022-01-12 06:35:00 N               <NA>           
#> 10  1010 2022-03-16 22:00:00 2022-04-06 11:35:00 N               <NA>           
#> 11  1010 2022-04-08 14:49:00 2022-04-12 12:36:00 Y               Y
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. During my conference I realized that the condition "<=72" is valid for "negative hours" (I couldn't say how this happens!). How would I go about limiting from 0 to 72?

Comment: I've added a possible approach to handle the above.

Comment: I tried to run the code again and now I get an error message: "object 'dmy_hm' not found". Would you have any knowledge of this bug?

Comment: Have you got the lubridate package loaded? Can you run the above reprex in a fresh R session?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a possible `dplyr` solution:

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

DF_1 %>% 
  mutate(across(2:3, dmy_hm),
         hours = floor(difftime(PATIENT_ADMISSION, lag(PATIENT_DISCHARGE), units="hours")),
         READMISSION_72H = case_when(PATIENT_READMISSION_30D == "Y" & hours <= 72 ~"Y", 
                                     PATIENT_READMISSION_30D == "Y" & hours >72 ~ "N"))
```

```
     ID   PATIENT_ADMISSION   PATIENT_DISCHARGE PATIENT_READMISSION_30D       hours READMISSION_72H
1   111 2022-03-18 15:30:00 2022-04-01 11:20:00                       N    NA hours            <NA>
2   222 2022-03-24 12:28:00 2022-03-26 12:56:00                       N  -191 hours            <NA>
3   222 2022-03-27 01:38:00 2022-03-27 17:52:00                       Y    12 hours               Y
4   333 2022-03-31 08:53:00 2022-04-01 16:15:00                       N    87 hours            <NA>
5   444 2022-04-16 22:45:00 2022-04-17 12:26:00                       N   366 hours            <NA>
6   444 2022-04-22 13:15:00 2022-04-25 14:54:00                       Y   120 hours               N
7   555 2022-04-05 05:44:00 2022-04-05 11:44:00                       N  -490 hours            <NA>
8   666 2022-03-30 06:16:00 2022-04-07 05:23:00                       N  -150 hours            <NA>
9  1010 2022-01-10 17:30:00 2022-01-12 06:35:00                       N -2076 hours            <NA>
10 1010 2022-03-16 22:00:00 2022-04-06 11:35:00                       N  1527 hours            <NA>
11 1010 2022-04-08 14:49:00 2022-04-12 12:36:00                       Y    51 hours               Y
```

Comment: Thanks. You didn't do the group_by by ID. Is it really not necessary to group?

Comment: No in this case it is not necessary. Because you indicate the grouping already with the "Y" in Patient_Readmission_30D.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `difftime()` with `dplyr::lag()` to calculate the time differences in hours and `dplyr::case_when()` to satisfy the conditions:

```
 # ensure proper format for dates
DF_1[2:3] <- lapply(DF_1[2:3], lubridate::dmy_hm)

DF_1 %>% mutate(PATIENT_READMISSION_72H_NEW = case_when(
  PATIENT_READMISSION_30D == "N" ~ "",
  difftime(PATIENT_ADMISSION, lag(PATIENT_DISCHARGE), units = "hours") <= 72 ~ "Y",
  difftime(PATIENT_ADMISSION, lag(PATIENT_DISCHARGE), units = "hours") > 72 ~ "N"
))
```

Output:

```
#     ID   PATIENT_ADMISSION   PATIENT_DISCHARGE PATIENT_READMISSION_30D PATIENT_READMISSION_72H
# 1   111 2022-03-18 15:30:00 2022-04-01 11:20:00                       N                        
# 2   222 2022-03-24 12:28:00 2022-03-26 12:56:00                       N                        
# 3   222 2022-03-27 01:38:00 2022-03-27 17:52:00                       Y                       Y
# 4   333 2022-03-31 08:53:00 2022-04-01 16:15:00                       N                        
# 5   444 2022-04-16 22:45:00 2022-04-17 12:26:00                       N                        
# 6   444 2022-04-22 13:15:00 2022-04-25 14:54:00                       Y                       N
# 7   555 2022-04-05 05:44:00 2022-04-05 11:44:00                       N                        
# 8   666 2022-03-30 06:16:00 2022-04-07 05:23:00                       N                        
# 9  1010 2022-01-10 17:30:00 2022-01-12 06:35:00                       N                        
# 10 1010 2022-03-16 22:00:00 2022-04-06 11:35:00                       N                        
# 11 1010 2022-04-08 14:49:00 2022-04-12 12:36:00                       Y                       Y
```

Comment: Thanks for the collaboration! This example that you disagreed with me was intentional, as I will see it in my routine. Possibly, your code compared line 9 with line 11. Your code should have compared the closest date (lines 10 and 11)

Comment: Thanks! I had slightly misread the question as duration of stay as 72 hours - the above edit to the code should work (and gives the desired result)

Comment: What does the lag function perform? Maybe the function will help me in other situations...

Comment: `dplyr::lag()` retrieves the value in the previous row. Note the base R `lag()` function does something different, so ensure you have `dplyr` loaded

Comment: Similar to @Carl, how would I put a range between 0 and 72? You just put "<=72"

Comment: If they are all integers you could change `<= 72` to `%in% 0:72` or if they are numeric you could do `between(difftime(PATIENT_ADMISSION, lag(PATIENT_DISCHARGE), units = "hours"), 0, 72)`